# Error in Fedora 9 while installing MySQL 5.5.20 using "YUM" Command

Tags: mysql, installation, fedora, yum

I am trying to install the latest version of MySQL server on a Fedora 9 machine. When I run the command `yum --enablerepo=remi list mysql mysql-server`, I get the error:

```
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
Error getting repository data for development, repository not found
```

Comment: I'm not sure Fedora 9 is even supported anymore. So you may have difficulties obtaining the packages you are seeking.  The current version of Fedora is 16.  You may have to build the packages from their sources.

Comment: I know that Fedora 16 s the latest version, but the machine  has been in production environment for too long and its impossible to upgrade it since lots of processes depend on it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that some sites do (amazingly) still carry mirrors of these older Fedora versions.

Have a look at the list on the [Fedora project website](http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/publiclist/Fedora/9/) and determine which one is best/closest to you, then edit your `yum` repositories as appropriate.

(I'm ignoring that you're using Fedora for a Production service...)